# Update 'Find my iPhone' location with new wireless network setup

Tags: ios, wifi, geolocation

Apple used to use [Skyhook Wireless](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/) to do geolocation on wifi devices to assist with GPS.

Now, according to their recent [location services press release](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/04/27location_qa.html), as well as previous iOS release notes,  they switched to an internal service to handle this. The recent PR said that they do still collect some of this information for their anon database.

Due to some changes in my wireless network (adding another base station), Find my iPhone isn't as accurate at my home anymore. It used to be very precise (could tell which side of the house a device was on), but now it shows the device across the street or in the trees.

Is there a way to manually update or refresh this location information? You used to be able to go to skyhooks website to enter your location and MAC addresses, but since Apple doesn't use that anymore - thats not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple has disclosed](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/04/27location_qa.html) that when you opt in to share anonymous diagnostic information it will occasionally update their database with data seen on your iOS device. Simply connect each device to iTunes and use the "reset all warnings" command so you will have a chance to re-opt in or out to sending diagnostic location and crash reports to Apple. There is currently no public facing way to seed their master database.

Comment: Yes, thats why I linked to that PR, I knew that they had their own database - just didn't know if there was a way to refresh it yet. I know I have all this already turned on. But like the last sentence of your answer, my assumption is correct - that Im not missing any front end to update it manually.