# Geolocation on Mac Pro

Tags: macos, mac, geolocation

Our Mac Pro is showing our old address as the location. How do we get it to change to new address?

We have switched on and off, reset and it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you moved with your own router and are still connected to it —on the new location— it may be that the database that holds the information about where your particular SSID, MAC or whatever information Apple uses to identify and geolocate network devices that conform it's "WPS" has not been updated yet.
[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/45630/38539) may be of help:

> The Mac can use Wi-Fi network identification for localization. This is called a Wi-Fi Positioning System (WPS). The access points name and signal strength is determined and looked up in a database to identify the location. The more access points are found, the more precise the localization.

[Apparently](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4221273?start=0&tstart=0), Apple used a commercial service called "Skyhook" where you could send your wifi and location data manually to update their database, but it seems they have their own location service now, which has, according to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13311):

> no public facing way to seed their master database.

On the same answer though, it states that:

> when you opt in to share anonymous diagnostic information it will occasionally update their database

So maybe opting in —if you haven't already— will speed up the relocation of your network on Apple's side.